# Google maps V3 getting kml description from overlay

Tags: google-maps

I found a KML file which has all the country data in it, which works great as an overlay, I've posted an example of one country from the KML file - My question is this:

I have turned off the infowindow using `suppressInfoWindows: true` How can I get the description tag contents as a var when the user clicks on the map? I know the click event part I just need to know how to obtain the information from the kml.

```
<Placemark><name>Aruba</name><description>ISO_A2=AW</description><LookAt><longitude>-69.98267466267889</longitude><latitude>12.52088880763951</latitude><heading>10.0</heading><tilt>10.0</tilt><range>700</range></LookAt><Style><IconStyle><color>00ffffff</color><scale>0.4</scale><Icon><href>http://icons.opengeo.org/markers/icon-poly.1.png</href></Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>00ffffff</color></LabelStyle><PolyStyle><color>ffD0D1E6</color><outline>1</outline></PolyStyle><LineStyle><color>ff000000</color><width>1</width></LineStyle></Style><MultiGeometry><Point><coordinates>-69.98267466267889,12.52088880763951</coordinates></Point><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-69.89913876,12.45200511 -69.89567644,12.42301463 -69.94215939,12.43851756 -70.00414527,12.50050344 -70.06613115,12.5469864 -70.05086077,12.5970867 -70.03512529,12.61411408 -69.97313941,12.56763113 -69.91179949,12.48047883 -69.89913876,12.45200511</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry></Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, just in case anybody else wants to know you add the listener to the kml and then use featureData on the click event - like this

> kml = new
>   google.maps.KmlLayer("http://whatever/countries_world.kml",{suppressInfoWindows:
>   true});
>
> kml.setMap(map);
>   google.maps.event.addListener(kml, 'click',
>   function(e) {
>
> ```
>      alert(e.featureData.name);
> ```
>
> }); 
>   }